# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry's skin is peeling off, he hides after Umbridge discovers it and finds Salazar's coffin

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I don't remember the name of the story or what site I read it on. However I remember the following points.

- Harry has some sort of creature inheritance (snake-based)
- his skin is peeling off and he hides it with gloves
- I believe it takes place in 5th year as Umbridge is in it
- Harry runs away when Umbridge tries to remove the gloves and glamours
- Harry hides behind a armor or in an alcove
- a small carving of a snake on the wall talks to him
- he goes into the chamber
- he finds Salazar's body in a coffin/sarcophagus
- Salazar's name is carved in to a door by Godric after Godric kills him

It has been a long time so I may be misremembering.